# Generate dynamic TilePane from Objects

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create dynamic TilePane which displays data from Java list of objects:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Random;  
import javafx.application.Application;  
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;  
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;  
import javafx.concurrent.Task;  
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;  
import javafx.event.EventHandler;  
import javafx.geometry.Insets;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;  
import javafx.scene.text.Text;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  
import javafx.util.Duration;  

public class MainApp extends Application  
{  

    final JVMDataService service = new JVMDataService();  

    Text one = new Text();  
    Text two = new Text();  
    Text three = new Text();  
    Text four = new Text();  

    @Override  
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception  
    {  

        Scene scene = new Scene(addGridPane());  

        datatask();  

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");  
        stage.setScene(scene);  
        stage.show();  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        launch(args);  
    }  

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();  

    public GridPane addGridPane()  
    {  

        grid.setHgap(10);  
        grid.setVgap(10);  
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));  

        Text category = new Text("Name 1");  
        grid.add(category, 0, 0);  

        grid.add(one, 1, 0);  

        grid.add(two, 2, 0);  

        grid.add(three, 3, 0);  

        grid.add(four, 4, 0);  

//        Text categos = new Text("Name 2");  
//        grid.add(categos, 0, 1);  
//  
//        grid.add(two, 1, 1);  
//  
//        grid.add(two, 2, 1);  
//  
//        grid.add(two, 3, 1);  
//  
//        grid.add(two, 4, 1);  
//  
//        Text cww = new Text("Name 3");  
//        grid.add(cww, 0, 2);  
//  
//        grid.add(three, 1, 2);  
//  
//        grid.add(three, 2, 2);  
//  
//        grid.add(three, 3, 2);  
//  
//        grid.add(three, 4, 2);  
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(30, 30, 30, 30));  

        return grid;  
    }  

    List<DataObj> myList;  

    public void datatask()  
    {  

        service.setDelay(new Duration(300));  
        service.setPeriod(new Duration(1000));  
        service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>()  
        {  
            @Override  
            public void handle(final WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent)  
            {  
                List<DataObj> results = (List<DataObj>) workerStateEvent.getSource().getValue();  

                for (DataObj element : results)  
                {  
                    one.setText(Integer.toString(element.getValueOne()));  
                    two.setText(Integer.toString(element.getValueTwo()));  
                    three.setText(Integer.toString(element.getValueThree()));  
                    four.setText(Integer.toString(element.getValueFour()));  
                }  
            }  
        });  
        service.start();  

    }  

    // Service  
    class JVMDataService extends ScheduledService<List<DataObj>>  
    {  
        @Override  
        protected Task<List<DataObj>> createTask()  
        {  
            final Task<List<DataObj>> voidTask = new Task<List<DataObj>>()  
            {  
                @Override  
                protected List<DataObj> call() throws Exception  
                {  
                    return getList();  
                }  
            };  

            return voidTask;  
        }  
    }  

    public List<DataObj> getList()  
    {  
        myList = new ArrayList<>();  
        Random rand = new Random();  

        int n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;  
        int s = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;  

        DataObj dd = new DataObj().newInstance().valueOne(n).valueTwo(s).valueThree(s).valueFour(s).valueFive(s);  
        DataObj dda = new DataObj().newInstance().valueOne(n + 2).valueTwo(s + 2).valueThree(s + 2).valueFour(s + 2).valueFive(s + 2);  
        DataObj dds = new DataObj().newInstance().valueOne(n + 22).valueTwo(s + 21).valueThree(s + 21).valueFour(s + 21).valueFive(s + 21);  
        DataObj ddd = new DataObj().newInstance().valueOne(n + 21).valueTwo(s + 23).valueThree(s + 23).valueFour(s + 23).valueFive(s + 23);  
        DataObj ddf = new DataObj().newInstance().valueOne(n + 25).valueTwo(s + 29).valueThree(s + 29).valueFour(s + 29).valueFive(s + 29);  

        myList.add(dd);  
        myList.add(dda);  
        myList.add(dds);  
        myList.add(ddd);  
        myList.add(ddf);  

        return myList;  
    }  

    public class DataObj  
    {  
        private int valueOne;  
        private int valueTwo;  
        private int valueThree;  
        private int valueFour;  
        private int valueFive;  

        public DataObj newInstance()  
        {  
            return new DataObj();  
        }  

        public DataObj()  
        {  
        }  

        public DataObj valueOne(int valueOne)  
        {  
            this.valueOne = valueOne;  
            return this;  
        }  

        public DataObj valueTwo(int valueTwo)  
        {  
            this.valueTwo = valueTwo;  
            return this;  
        }  

        public DataObj valueThree(int valueThree)  
        {  
            this.valueThree = valueThree;  
            return this;  
        }  

        public DataObj valueFour(int valueFour)  
        {  
            this.valueFour = valueFour;  
            return this;  
        }  

        public DataObj valueFive(int valueFive)  
        {  
            this.valueFive = valueFive;  
            return this;  
        }  

        public int getValueOne()  
        {  
            return valueOne;  
        }  

        public int getValueTwo()  
        {  
            return valueTwo;  
        }  

        public int getValueThree()  
        {  
            return valueThree;  
        }  

        public int getValueFour()  
        {  
            return valueFour;  
        }  

        public int getValueFive()  
        {  
            return valueFive;  
        }  

    }  

}
```

Th problem is that the list of Objects is dynamic. I need to display every time TilePane with different size. Can you help me to solve this problem? Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hej Peter,

have you tried to put the `TilePane` into a `ScrollPane`, so you can scroll to the right if there are more `Columns`. Another idea is to increase the number of the `Rows` within the `TilePane`.

I have a small example, i used a `Person` class, not your `DataObject`.

Here is the Service class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

/**
 *
 * @author Patrick Ott <Patrick.Ott@professional-webworkx.de>
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class JVMDataService extends ScheduledService<List<Person>> {

    private final Random generator = new Random();

    @Override
    protected Task<List<Person>> createTask() {
        return new Task<List<Person>>() {

            @Override
            protected List<Person> call() throws Exception {
                int n = generator.nextInt(50);
                List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    System.out.println("i = " + i);
                    persons.add(new Person("Max", "Mustermann", "max" + i + ".mustermann@example.com"));
                }
                return persons;
            }
        };
    };

}
```

And the App class

```
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    JVMDataService service = new JVMDataService();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 768);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        final TilePane tilePane = new TilePane(Orientation.VERTICAL, 25, 20);
        tilePane.setPrefRows(15);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(tilePane);
        scrollPane.setPrefViewportWidth(1100);
        scrollPane.setPrefViewportHeight(650);
        final VBox vBox = new VBox(scrollPane);

        service.setDelay(Duration.seconds(3));
                // time between every Period / Run
                service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(3));
                service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                        List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) t.getSource().getValue();
                        for (Person person : persons) {
                            tilePane.getChildren().add(new Text(person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastNameProperty().get() + ", " + person.geteMailProperty().get()));
                        }
                    }
                });
                service.start();


        hBox.getChildren().add(vBox);

        root.getChildren().add(hBox);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here is the Person class..

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class Person implements Serializable {

    private StringProperty firstNameProperty    = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty lastNameProperty     = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty eMailProperty        = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String email) {
        this.firstNameProperty.set(firstName);
        this.lastNameProperty.set(lastName);
        this.eMailProperty.set(email);
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstNameProperty
     */
    public StringProperty getFirstNameProperty() {
        return firstNameProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstNameProperty.get();
    }

    /**
     * @param firstNameProperty the firstNameProperty to set
     */
    public void setFirstNameProperty(StringProperty firstNameProperty) {
        this.firstNameProperty = firstNameProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastNameProperty
     */
    public StringProperty getLastNameProperty() {
        return lastNameProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastNameProperty the lastNameProperty to set
     */
    public void setLastNameProperty(StringProperty lastNameProperty) {
        this.lastNameProperty = lastNameProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eMailProperty
     */
    public StringProperty geteMailProperty() {
        return eMailProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @param eMailProperty the eMailProperty to set
     */
    public void seteMailProperty(StringProperty eMailProperty) {
        this.eMailProperty = eMailProperty;
    }
}
```

The Result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Well, in my case I need to generate a list with Linux processes - so this list id very dynamic and it's changed in every run. Can you show me some example with dynamically generated list of data where the size is changed in every run?

Comment: The size of the Lists is changing randomly  in the above example.

Comment: Could you please paste the complete code because the Object is missing?

Comment: How I can make the Service to be infinite I would like to update the data every for example 3 seconds without pressing the button.

Comment: You can use `// delay before running the first time
                service.setDelay(Duration.seconds(3));
                // time between every Period / Run
                service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(3));` i updated the Code. In the above example you have to press once the button to start the service, then it will run infinite times with a delay of 3 seconds.

Comment: It's not working properly - the data is not updated. You can remove the button, I don't need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58116/discussion-between-patrick-and-peter-penzov).